# How to query value from specific Realtime Database path?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I've written a Firebase Cloud Function that pushes a notification to a topic whenever a certain value (`timeTag`) is changed:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/books/{category}/pages/{page}/timeTag').onUpdate((change, context) => {

    const category = context.params.category;
    const page = context.params.page;

    const categoryName = admin.database().ref('/books/'+`${category}`+'/name/');
    const pageName = admin.database().ref('/books/'+`${category}`+'/pages/'+`${page}`+'/name/');

    const data = change.data;
    console.log(`${categoryName}`)
    console.log(`${pageName}`)

    console.log('Message received');

    const payLoad = {
        notification:{
            title: 'There's an update in '+`${categoryName}`,
            body:  'The page that's been updated is '+`${pageName}`,
            sound: "default"
        }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("all", payLoad);
});
```

The database is structured like this:

```
books:
      {categoryID}
      name: categoryName
      pages:
            {pageID}
            name: pageName
```

Currently the names are the complete URL's in the database; for example, `https://my-project.firebaseio.com/books/-LxzDYhk-t3LGRGifEyz/name`. In this case, `name` is the key for the value I want. This is problematic because the FCM notification ends up being `There's an update in https://my-project.firebaseio.com/books/-LxzDYhk-t3LGRGifEyz/name` instead of `There's an update in categoryOne`.

What I'm trying to do is set the variables as the values for the `name` keys, instead of the URLs themselves. What have I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is.  Please edit the question to clarify what you mean by "the names are the complete paths in the database", and why that's a problem here.  It will be helpful if you provide specific examples.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating references to the data, but not actually fetching it. You need something like this:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/books/{category}/pages/{page}/timeTag').onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

    // ...

    const categoryNameSnap = await admin.database().ref('/books/'+`${category}`+'/name/').once('value');
    const categoryName = categoryNameSnap.val();
    const pageNameSnap = await admin.database().ref('/books/'+`${category}`+'/pages/'+`${page}`+'/name/').once('value');
    const pageName = pageNameSnap.val();

    // ...
});
```

Note that the function has been made async (to allow for a wait on the promise returned by `.once('value')` and the values are being pulled from the resulting snapshot.

[These docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) have some more info generally about retrieving data from the Realtime Database.

Comment: Thanks, however I ran into an issue with your solution - `TypeError: .val is not a function`. I tried to change `.val()` to `.value` and that runs successfully, but the `categoryName` and `pageName` are returned as `undefined`. Also - the notification is marked as sent, but is never received on the device...